# How to tweet image with its url

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using twitter api to make a bot with javascript and I wanted to know if it's possible to tweet an image with it's url. For example I tweet an imgur image with my bot and it will show like a normal image in twitter.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that. You need to upload the image to Twitter using the media upload API.